# Replacing all digits(not specific digits) with asterisk in a file with one try using c program?

Tags: c

How do i change all digits into asterisk in a file that contains digits and words?my sorce code only allows me to change once at a time and it is hectic.In this code, i have already inserted open file,replace and close file.For your information, this is my first year project as a university student and i wasnt good at programming in c yet.Therefore, i have been scratching my head and searching for every help possible but to no avail.The title for this year project is number redaction but overall it means replace everysingle piece ofsensitive information that contains numbers(zero to nine)(in a file)into asterisk.Sensitive information like credit card number,debit card number,bank account number,house address and even phone number.My sincere gratitude to those who wish to help me!Thank you!

```
#include <stdio.h>
  #include <string.h>
  #define MAX 256

  int main() {
        FILE *fp1, *fp2;
        char word[MAX], fname[MAX];
        char string[MAX], replace[MAX];
        char temp[] = "temp.txt", *ptr1, *ptr2;

        /* get the input file from the user */
        printf("Enter your input file name:");
        fgets(fname, MAX, stdin);
        fname[strlen(fname) - 1] = '\0';

        /* get the word to delete from the user */
        printf("Enter the word to be replaced:");
        scanf("%s", word);

        /* get the word to replace */
        printf("Enter your replace word:");
        scanf("%s", replace);

        /* open input file in read mode */
        fp1 = fopen(fname, "r");

        /* error handling */
        if (!fp1) {
                printf("Unable to open the input file!!\n");
                return 0;
        }

        /* open temporary file in write mode */
        fp2 = fopen(temp, "w");

        /* error handling */
        if (!fp2) {
                printf("Unable to open temporary file!!\n");
                return 0;
        }

        /* delete the given word from the file */
        while (!feof(fp1)) {
                strcpy(string, "\0");
                /* read line by line from the input file */
                fgets(string, MAX, fp1);

                /*
                 * check whether the word to delete is
                 * present in the current scanned line
                 */
                if (strstr(string, word)) {
                        ptr2 = string;
                        while (ptr1 = strstr(ptr2, word)) {
                                /*
                                 * letters present before
                                 * before the word to be replaced
                                 */
                                while (ptr2 != ptr1) {
                                        fputc(*ptr2, fp2);
                                        ptr2++;
                                }
                                /* skip the word to be replaced */
                                ptr1 = ptr1 + strlen(word);
                                fprintf(fp2, "%s", replace);
                                ptr2 = ptr1;
                        }

                        /* characters present after the word to be replaced */
                        while (*ptr2 != '\0') {
                                fputc(*ptr2, fp2);
                                ptr2++;
                        }
                } else {
                        /*
                         * current scanned line doesn't 
                         * have the word that need to be replaced
                         */
                        fputs(string, fp2);
                }
        }

        /* close the opened files */
        fclose(fp1);
        fclose(fp2);

        /* remove the input file */
        remove(fname);
        /* rename temporary file name to input file name */
        rename(temp, fname);
        return 0;
  }
```

Comment: `while (!feof(fp1))` is wrong because `feof` tells you the _previous_ read operation failed.

Comment: @user3121023 yes ..howver the coding should automatically replace them with **** because typing every single number list is too hectic.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie hey sir, can you perhaps let me have a look at how you will do it?Thanks

Comment: do you need to replace ALL numbers in the file, or only specific patterns of numbers?

Comment: @div0man all numbers sir

Comment: then what @user3121023 said, char by char is way simpler, you could even do it in-place without the temporary file

Comment: @user3121023 can you show me how?I am still new to programming thanks mate!!

Comment: @WinsonLee - You will learn more by working out how to turn user3121923's suggestion into code than you would if someone was to simply give you code.    In any event, break the problem down into steps.   Work out how to read a single character from a file,  Work out how to check if a character is a digit.  Work out how to write a character.    Add error checking on each operation, and write a loop that reads a character, checks if it is a digit, and then writes output, until an end condition (e.g. end of file indication) occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're replacing a char, don't make the job hard for yourself by writing a program to replace words, creating unnecessary complexity in the program. Below is a very simple approach.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 256

bool isNum(char c)
{
    if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

int main(void) {
    FILE *fp1, *fp2;
    char fname[MAX];
    char temp[] = "temp.txt";

    /* get the input file from the user */
    printf("Enter your input file name:");
    fgets(fname, MAX, stdin);
    fname[strlen(fname) - 1] = '\0';

    /* open input file in read mode */
    fp1 = fopen(fname, "r");

    /* error handling */
    if (!fp1) {
            printf("Unable to open the input file!!\n");
            return 0;
    }

    /* open temporary file in write mode */
    fp2 = fopen(temp, "w");

    /* error handling */
    if (!fp2) {
            printf("Unable to open temporary file!!\n");
            return 0;
    }

    int c = getc(fp1);
    while (c != EOF)
    {
        if (isNum((char) c))
            c = '*';
        putc(c, fp2);
        c = getc(fp1);
    }

    /* close the opened files */
    fclose(fp1);
    fclose(fp2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: sir,when i type in my file name,it says unable to open file

Comment: Works fine for me, tested with `asterisk.c`, got my code in `temp.txt` with digits masked

Comment: oh sir there has been a mistake on my code.Adjusted already.Thank you so much sir!!

Comment: You're welcome, and welcome to stackexchange! Btw, comments are mostly for clarifications and not for thank yous and chats :) Stick around, try to help others or just make it a habit to check what problems others are dealing with, and you'll learn in the process. I'm also learning C, but from K&R book and from hanging around here. Anyways, if you're happy with the answer, please mark your question as answered.